# Excel returning external value using two comparative values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have an excel sheet that looks like this:

```
age q01 q02 q03
1   0.5 0.6 0.8
2   0.6 0.9 1.2
```

There are quantile values from my variable of interest for a number of age values. Now, I would like to create an excel-calculator where you can enter age and the value a certain person achieved and it returns on which quantile the person is located.
For example: A Person is 2 years old and achieved 1.0 points in a test. The excel formula then should return "q02" as the closest value is 0.9 which is in the column "q02".

Comment: if the value is in between two the higher value should be returned. Thanks so much for your help pnuts!

Comment: Not sure about a formula, you can do this in VBA is VBA is an option

Comment: @ehi your example clearly says an age of 2 and a score of 1 should return 0.9 not 1.2 as its closer, but then you say in your comment that it should always be the higher value, my answer below is based on closest no next highest FYI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a formula, there are 3 basic parts, find the row matching the age, find the column closest to the score, return the value in this row/column. Assuming your example table is in A1:D3 I set up a few cells so that Age is in F2, Score is in G2, result row is H2, result col is I2 and result is J2, formulas are:

```
H2 = MATCH(F2, A2:A3)
I2 = MATCH(MIN(ABS(G2-OFFSET(B1:D1, H2, 0))), ABS(G2-OFFSET(B1:D1, H2, 0)))
```

I2 is the tricky part, it is an array formula so you must hold CTRL+SHIFT when you enter the formula, basically it looks at H2 which has already identified the row that matches the Age, then it finds the absolute value of the difference of each value in the row and the score, then it finds the min difference (the closest value) and then determines the position of that value in the array (which gives your matching column)

```
J2 = OFFSET(A1, H2, I2)
```

J2 just uses offset to return the value with your result row/col

Sorry to have to use 'helper' cells but I couldn't get OFFSET to use the array result of I2 directly